# Warning about unhandled type class during compilation

Tags: scala, sbt

Given the following minimal code:

```
package object MyPackage {
  case class Pimp(private val i: Int) extends AnyVal 
}
```

SBT (0.13.8) complains:

```
[warn] sbt-api: Unhandled type class scala.reflect.internal.Types$MethodType : ($this: myPackage.package.Pimp)Int
```

My build file is roughly this:

```
Project("sbtissue", file("sbtissue")).settings(scalaVersion := "2.11.6")
```

Changing the relevant line in the source file to:

```
class Pimp(private val i: Int) extends AnyVal
```

or:

```
case class Pimp(i: Int) extends AnyVal
```

raises no warning when compiling.
What can I do to prevent this warning?

Related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/KWdg4HfYqMk

Answer (score 4):

I think you've found a legitimate edge case, if a little niche maybe.

I would recommend dropping the `private` as it doesn't really fit with the idea of a case class, and also, given the existence of a generated unapply, it doesn't hide that value anyways:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_40).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> case class Pimp(private val i: Int) extends AnyVal
defined class Pimp

scala> val p1 = Pimp(1)
p1: Pimp = Pimp(1)

scala> p1.i
<console>:11: error: value i is not a member of Pimp
              p1.i
                 ^

scala> val Pimp(n) = p1
n: Int = 1
```